# how to print the file with particular extension in a directory?

Tags: linux, shell

I tried the below command to print the files with `.txt` extension in a current directory.But it is not working not.can anyone help with other shell script solution?

```
for i_dir in *
do
   var=`find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -name '$i_dir*.txt'`
   echo $var
done
```

Answer (score 0):

By 'print the files', do you mean list their names? Then it's simply

```
ls *.txt
```

And add `-a` if you need to see the hidden ones as well:

```
ls -a *.txt
```

`ls` is one of the eldest Unix commands, it's two-consonant derived from 'list' (others are `cp` for 'copy', `rm` for 'remove', `cd` for 'change directory'...).